# Apple Watch: Why the APP forced to stop when using CMSensorRecorder?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos-2, core-motion

I used [CMSensorRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMSensorRecorder_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016255-CH1-SW7) to record historical Accelerometer data, and *accelerometerData(from:to:)* to retrieve past data. But if I record 1 hour or more, the APP always forced stop when **retrieving**, I can hardly receive data of that time.

When **Recording**, everything is okay like Pic1, while press "Stop" to **Retrieve data**, it became like Pic2. **The Question is**: if I want to record a long time data, the Pic2 will continues very long and mostly cause the APP shutdown! Then nearly all data will lose!

[image: Recording] & [image: Retrieving]

My code below:

```
if CMSensorRecorder.isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable(){
    Now = NSDate()
    recorder.recordAccelerometerForDuration(time)
    print("\n\n\nRecording Accel!...........\n")
}else{
    print("Need Authorization to record!...\n")
    self.EatingButton.setTitle("AuthFail")
}
// retrieve data from watch
let sensorDataList = recorder.accelerometerDataFromDate(Now, toDate: NSDate())
if (sensorDataList == nil){
   SButton.setTitle("Failed")
}else{
   for data in sensorDataList!
   {
      //Send data to iPhone
      self.sendAccel("\(data.startDate) \(data.acceleration.x) \(data.acceleration.y) \(data.acceleration.z)")
   }
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Whether there are some relationship to **NSProcessInfo** function?

Comment: I used an audio play to call the main thread every 30 seconds, The CoreMotion can run background now. Because only if you play a music, the apple cannot kill your app.

Comment: Can you explain how you do it? ('call the main thread every 30 seconds') And did Apple approve it?